# SAS How to set up line plot

Tags: sas

I have code that creates a table for me that looks like this, and I would like to graph it. However, the chart turns out like this. How to do it to show only the dates without OLD, or to have OLD as one point on the graph.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nqlmt.png)

This is my code:

```
proc format;
    value vintf low-'31JUL2020'd = 'OLD' other=[yymmd7.];
run;

proc summary data=diff nway;
    class policy_vintage;
    format policy_vintage vintf.;
    var POLICY_TODAY POLICY_PRIOR;
    output out=newdiff sum=;
    
proc sql;
    create table diff1 as
        select today.policy_vintage
             , POLICY_TODAY
             , POLICY_PRIOR
             , POLICY_TODAY - POLICY_PRIOR as DIFFERENCE
        from newdiff today
        LEFT JOIN
             (select *
              from _work.POLICY_VINTAGE_WEEKLY
              where run_date < today()
              having run_date = max(run_date)
             ) prior
        ON today.policy_vintage = prior.policy_vintage
   ;
quit;
proc sgplot data=diff1;
series x=policy_vintage y=POLICY_TODAY / markerattrs=(color=vligb symbol=circlefilled size=20) 
          lineattrs=(color=vligb thickness=2);
series x=policy_vintage y=POLICY_PRIOR / y2axis markerattrs=(color=salmon symbol=circlefilled size=9) 
          lineattrs=(color=salmon thickness=2);
run;
```

This is plot which i got:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7CTU0.png)

Comment: Have you tried using the XAXIS statement to limit what is shown, and/or using WHERE to filter the data to only dates you are interested in?

Comment: When i tried use where Policy_vintage ne "Old" i git error WHERE clause operator requires compatible variables

Comment: Sounds like you have a numeric variable with a format, then (as you obviously do).  You need `where policy_vinatge gt '01AUG2020'd` or similar.